# Spring integration Java - how to use @InboundChannelAdapter to check a directory for files?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, dsl, inbound

How can i get `@InboundChannelAdapter` to work with files? something like this:

```
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="executionMessageFileInputChannel"
                                      directory="file:${fpml.messages.input}"
                                      prevent-duplicates="false" filename-pattern="*.xml">
        <int:poller fixed-delay="20000" max-messages-per-poll="1" />
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

but in java?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this:

```
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "executionMessageFileInputChannel",
        poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "20000", maxMessagesPerPoll = "1"))
public MessageSource<File> fileMessageSource(@Value("${fpml.messages.input}") File directory) {
    FileReadingMessageSource fileReadingMessageSource = new FileReadingMessageSource();
    fileReadingMessageSource.setDirectory(directory);
    fileReadingMessageSource.setFilter(new SimplePatternFileListFilter("*.xml"));
    return fileReadingMessageSource;
}
```

From other side pay attention, please, to the [Spring Integration Java DSL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki/Spring-Integration-Java-DSL-Reference) project, using which the same may look like:

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow fileReadingFlow(@Value("${fpml.messages.input}") File directory) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(s -> s.file(directory).patternFilter("*.xml"),
                        e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(20000)))
        .....................
                .get();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, it works. Also, I've updated the question requesting a bit more information, Would be great if you could have a look. Cheers!

Comment: Please, ask that question in the separate SO thread. It doesn't relate to the current one.

Comment: Sure, new thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31845269/spring-integration-how-to-use-inbound-channel-adapter-to-check-a-directory-for